# Gulp Command Run Never Finish

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I have bought template MaterialPro from [wrappixel](https://www.wrappixel.com/demos/admin-templates/material-pro/landingpage/index.html) website. After I got the template package already, I have followed getting started installation from document attached with template as the  following:

1. Install Node.js From https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Open terminal navigating to `material-pro/`
3. Install npm: `npm install --global npm@latest`
4. Install yarn: `npm install --global yarn`
5. Install gulp: `npm install --global gulp-cli`
6. Copy gulp: `gulp copy`

The `gulpfile.js` inside root template is like this:

```
//gulpfile.js
console.time("Loading plugins"); //start measuring
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    npmDist = require('gulp-npm-dist');
console.timeEnd('Loading plugins');

const sassFiles = 'src/assets/scss/*.scss',
    cssDest = 'dist/css/';

//compile scss into css
function style() {
    return gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
}

//This is for the minify css
async function minifycss() {
    return gulp.src(['dist/css/*.css', '!dist/css/**/*.min.css'])
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
}

// This is for the minifyjs
async function minifyjs() {
    return gulp.src(['dist/js/custom.js','dist/js/app.js', '!dist/js/custom.min.js',  '!dist/js/app.min.js'] )
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
}

// Copy dependencies to ./public/libs/
async function copy() {
    gulp.src(npmDist(), {
            base: './node_modules'
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/assets/libs'));
};

async function watch() {
    gulp.watch(['src/assets/scss/**/*.scss'], style);
    gulp.watch(['dist/css/style.css'], minifycss);
    gulp.watch(['dist/js/**/*.js', '!dist/js/**/*.min.js'], minifyjs);
}


gulp.task('default', watch);

exports.style = style;
exports.minifycss = minifycss;
exports.minifyjs = minifyjs;
exports.copy = copy;
exports.watch = watch;
```

After all, I made some changes to the template scss file, and run `gulp` command. At this point, the gulp command run never finished unitl now with output on terminal like this

```
Loading plugins: 539.410ms
[17:01:03] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/documentation/materialpro-bootstrap-latest/material-pro/gulpfile.js
[17:01:03] Starting 'default'...
[17:01:03] Finished 'default' after 18 ms
```

What was going wrong with this? Please kindly help, thanks.

P.S: Pls apologized if my question is incomplete or something, if I will try to add some more detail if suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gulp code is fine. Made some change on your scss or js file it will show some changes.

Exaplantion

1. Your default command is `gulp.task('default', watch);`
2. when you run `gulp` it starts to watch your scss, css, js code. If there is new change it will execute the command.

Suggestion. Use like this.

```
async function watch() {
    gulp.watch(['src/assets/scss/**/*.scss'], style, minifycss);
    gulp.watch(['dist/js/**/*.js', '!dist/js/**/*.min.js'], minifyjs);
}
```

Comment: In your scss file you have imported `@import of "icons/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.css" and that path is not correct or that css file require some font files. may be that one is missing as well. Please check and let me know. If everything is fine then add that file to ignore for the time being if it is stopping you for further development. And also share your scss files

Comment: I run gulp style, gulp minifycss, and gulp minifyjs, they worked fine, except when I run gulp everything was hanged again. also I already changed as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I did, so I have copied fontawsesome to folder dist, so i got rid of that error. but still command `gulp` still hanged :)

Comment: Nice. But that hanged situation is expected as you are watching it. What watch mean: Gulp will wait for new change if it find the change it will run those command again. No need to run the watch command again. Please change a scss or js file you will see watch file is workin.

Comment: Ah yes, that's it I see the change, the gulp command is never ended. Thanks very much that you help me out :)

Comment: Good to know. It helped

Comment: Sorry to be back again, but when i closed and open project again then run the `gulp` command output an error when I made some changes to scss file: ``Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src/assets/scss/style.scss
Error: It's not clear which file to import for '@import "bootstrap/bootstrap"'.
       Candidates:
         bootstrap/bootstrap.scss
         bootstrap/bootstrap.css
       Please delete or rename all but one of these files.
        on line 9 of src/assets/scss/style.scss
>> @import 'bootstrap/bootstrap';  ```

Comment: import like this `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Comment: yes, i found an boostrap.css, and other css file inside dist/bootstrap folders, I thought they were created from vs code extension sass live compiler that I activated it a moment ago. So I removed those css files and they worked again, Thanks so much :)